# How do I delay delivery in Outlook for Mac 2016 without Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm using Outlook for Mac 2016 version 16.12 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 with a Microsoft Exchange mailbox. I'd like to send an e-mail in the future, but schedule it today. I understand that this feature is called "delay delivery." However, it appears that Microsoft has only enabled this feature for Outlook users with an Office 365 mailbox.

**Question**: How do I delay delivery of an e-mail, using Outlook for Mac 2016, with a Microsoft Exchange mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

To delay deliver a message in Outlook for Mac 2016, your system needs to meet these requirements:

- An Office 365 Business Premium or Enterprise subscription. (Office
  365 Home, Personal, Student, and Business don't include Exchange so
  will not work with this feature.)
- An Exchange-based email account hosted on Office 365 or on Exchange
  2016 CU5 and later. An Exchange-based email account can be an Outlook
  account or a connected Hotmail or Outlook.com account.
- Outlook 2016 for Mac version 15.35.170509 and later (select Outlook >
  About Outlook to check your version).

If above requirements are not met, you won't be able to use this feature.

See the following Microsoft official article for more details:

[Delay or schedule the delivery of email messages in Outlook 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delay-or-schedule-the-delivery-of-email-messages-in-outlook-2016-for-mac-a02097de-76c2-4895-9557-0818ef229024)